# Pandas read_csv delimeters different positions

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I newbie in Python and I'm trying to learn by jobs that I did using VBA (Macro-Excel)

The TXT file that I want to read you can download [here](http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/InstDados/SerHist/COTAHIST_A2009.ZIP). The content is historical quote data from B3 (Brazilian Stock Market)

If you want to understanding better how is the layout of file you can download this [file](http://www.b3.com.br/data/files/65/50/AD/26/29C8B51095EE46B5790D8AA8/HistoricalQuotations_B3.pdf)

In below there's a VBA code that I use read the TXT file.

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="COTAHIST_A2009.TXT"  _
    Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=2, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:= _
    Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 4), Array(10, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(27, 1), _
    Array(39, 1), Array(49, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(56, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(82, 1), Array( _
    95, 1), Array(108, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(134, 1), Array(147, 1), Array(152, 1), Array( _
    170, 1), Array(188, 1), Array(201, 1), Array(202, 1), Array(210, 1), Array(217, 1), Array( _
    230, 1), Array(242, 1), Array(245, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

This part **Array(Array(0, 1), ...,  Array(245, 1))** basic specified the position of the delimeter. And this that I want to know to do in Python. Be more specific how to adjust the read_csv command to read apropriate the file.
I considerer the solution could be a pre processing stage before read a TXT file with read_csv.

I appreciate the patience and I hope you can help me.

Comment: Maybe [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) is more appropriate here.

Comment: @BigBen, thanks for answering. I'm going to try use your idea.